# How to use explicit customer parameters in a recommender system?

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am trying to improve the recommendation system, but I do not know how to do it better.
I have the following data frames:

```
purchases['customer_id','product_id','datetime']
```

and

`customers['customer_id','sex']`

I create compressed sparse row matrix (csr_matrix) and fit the model:

```
model = implicit.als.AlternatingLeastSquares(factors=64, iterations=100)
```

After fitting the model, you can get the matrix of factors of customers and products (whith 64 factors):

```
u_f = model.user_factors, i_f = model.item_factors
```

Before training the model, I added purchases of "Male" and "Female" to customers who know the gender. But this almost did not affect the quality of the model. I tried to add the factors "Male" and "Female" after factorization, but I could not do it.
**How can i use customers gender to improve the quality of the model?**